# File browser keeps crashing

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Hi all need some help with my program here.

Every time i run it the first window appears but the program crashes when I press the browse button.

Im also not getting any error on NetBeans. It just says Build Successful.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you.

Code:

```
public class MyJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        List<String> optionList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        optionList1.add("Cancel");
        optionList1.add("Browse");

        Object[] options1 = optionList1.toArray();

        int value1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Please select the file you want to encrypt:",
                "Open",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options1,
                optionList1.get(0));

        String option1 = optionList1.get(value1);

        if (value1 == 1) {

            JFrame frame = null;
            JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
            int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(frame);
            File myFile = fChoose.getSelectedFile();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1"));
            String line;
            while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("The text is\n" +line);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the console to see the exception you got.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Im sorry can you tell me how to get to the console?

Comment: It works fine on my computer.

Comment: @neoprez Ok thanks I shall try rebooting my computer.

Comment: Rebooting didnt help either...

Comment: So when you click browse, do you get to pick something or it happens immediately after you press the button?

Comment: @neoprez Nothing happens when I press browse and netbeans just says the program is running.

Comment: do you have any other code that you are not showing?

Comment: @neoprez Nope thats all the code I have. It worked once when I stopped the running and started it again and once when restarted Netbeans.